# $\int_1^n g(x)dx = \log (n!) - \frac {\log n}{2} - \frac{1}{8n}+ \frac{1}{8}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $m \in \mathbb N$ and $g(x)=\frac{x}{m}-1+\log m$, if $m-\frac{1}{2} \le x<m+\frac{1}{2}$

I need to prove that $\int_1^n g(x)dx = \log (n!) - \frac {\log n}{2} - \frac{1}{8n}+ \frac{1}{8}$. I drew the graph of the function and noticed the integral is the sum of areas of several trapezoids but I cannot quite get the right formula.

Comment: Start by calculating $\int_{m-1/2}^{m+1/2} g(x) dx$ in general using the formula you are given and use $\int_1^n g(x) dx = \int_1^{3/2}g(x) dx + \sum_{m=2}^{n-1} \int_{m-1/2}^{m+1/2}g(x)dx + \int_{n-1/2}^n g(x) dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_1^n g(x) dx &= \int_1^{3/2} g(x) dx+\sum_{m=2}^{n-1}\int_{m-1/2}^{m+1/2}g(x)dx+\int_{n-1/2}^n g(x) dx\\\\
&=\int_1^{3/2} (x/1-1+\log1) dx\\
&+\sum_{m=2}^{n-1}\int_{m-1/2}^{m+1/2}(x/m-1+\log m)dx\\
&+\int_{n-1/2}^n (x/n-1+\log n) dx\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?